# How to unlock without the mouse?

Tags: greeter, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, lock

When I try to unlock, I'm unable to focus the password input without clicking the mouse, is there a way around this so I can focus the input without a mouse? There doesn't appear to be any setting for this in system settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a confirmed bug : [Password input not in focus #144](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/144)